# i will not get perfect address in the label using location manager method

Tags: ios, dictionary, label, cllocationmanager

hey friends i will implement the code to get current address.but problem is i will not get perfect location but provide some some another near location so pls solve my problem

map.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_lat;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_long;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_address;
- (IBAction)location:(id)sender;
@end
```

map.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)location:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        self.lbl_long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        self.lbl_lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            self.lbl_address.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];
}
```

thanks for in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can you set `desiredAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` instead of `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer`.

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

`kCLLocationAccuracyBest` sets accuracy to the highest-level of accuracy. By using `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` you set accuracy to the nearest kilometre, thus you are not getting exact location.